# Wait for a screen -X stuff "script" to finish

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have a `screen` instance running on remote machine. I want to execute commands on that screen like this:

```sh
ssh serverIp screen -S remote -p 0 -X stuff \"./build.sh^M\"
rsync -arvcL serverIp:/path/to/build.log build.log
```

The `build.sh` script invokes some `make` commands on the remote and saves it's output (using `tee`) to some file (let's call it `build.log`). Then I want to download `build.log` to my local machine.

**How do I wait for the `./buils.sh` to finish on remote**, so I can download complete `build.log`?

Answer (score 1):

You could wait for a file, created after your build script finished.

Something like

**start-build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
./build.sh
touch build.done
```

Then the command looks like:

```
ssh server 'rm -f build.done; screen -S remote -X stuff "./start-build^M"; while [ ! -f build.done ]; do sleep 1; done'
```

First it removes an old `build.done` file, then start the build inside the screen.
And then wait (outside of the screen) for the file `build.done` to exist.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that suggestion. I've already did something similar using fifo pipes, and it works, but I'm looking for a more "clean" way